# T-SQL stored procedure has stopped returning value retrieved from URL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have used the following code for years to convert a Bank Routing Number into the Bank Name that gets inserted into a Payroll Stub. It recently stopped returning a value. No error. Just an empty string.

Has something changed with T-SQL that renders this obsolete?  ^Is there a better way to do this?

```
-- stored procedure params:  sample bank ID = 121000358
@bankid varchar(9)
@bankname varchar(100) OUTPUT

exec sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
RECONFIGURE;  

declare @obj int
declare @url varchar(60)
declare @response varchar(500)
declare @bankinfo varchar(500)

set @url = 'https://www.routingnumbers.info/api/data.json?rn=' + @bankid

exec sp_OACreate  'MSXML2.XMLHTTP',@obj OUT;
exec sp_OAMethod @obj,'open',NULL,'get',@url,'false'
exec sp_OAMethod @obj,'send'
exec sp_OAMethod @obj,'responseText',@response OUTPUT   
set @bankinfo = (select @response [response])

declare @left varchar(500)
declare @right varchar(500)
declare @delimiter1 varchar(18) = '"customer_name": "'
declare @delimiter2 varchar(6) = '"'
declare @outStr varchar(200)


declare @pos int = (charindex(@delimiter1,@bankinfo) + 18)
set @bankinfo = substring(@bankinfo,@pos,len(@bankinfo))
set @pos = charindex(@delimiter2,@bankinfo)
set @bankinfo = substring(@bankinfo,0,@pos)
set @bankname = @bankinfo

--select @bankname

exec sp_OADestroy @obj

exec sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 0;  
RECONFIGURE;
```

Comment: Have you checked if the service simply went down?

Comment: Yes, if I submit the url with the bank ID, it does return me the values I am looking for.

Comment: I just copy and pasted your code into SSMS and it returned "BANK OF AMERICA, N.A." which I assume is correct for bank id "121000358". Are you observing the blank value in SSMS or in your application?

Comment: You have no error handling.  Fix that first, following, eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46102766/how-to-call-web-service-from-t-sql/46103163#46103163

Comment: Do you have other stored procedures that follow this pattern of enabling Ole Automation Procedures, doing something and disabling them again? You've probably created your own race condition.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The Ops team at my company isolated this SQL server from the internet. Thus the call to the URL comes back empty, but when I manually make the call from my laptop, it makes the trip there and back.